# Show "add activity" on fullcalendar day hover

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to show "add activity" when I hover over a day in fullcalendar (month view). I have used the following code - and it works in all but IE8. Any ideas how to make this work in IE8? It just flickers unpredictably.

```
$('.fc-day').hover(function(){
    $(this).find('.fc-day-content').prepend("<span id='addToggle'>Add activity</span>");
},
function(){
    $(this).find('#addToggle').remove();
});
```

Comment: Is your mouse hovering over the newly added `span`, causing the `hoverOut` to fire?

Comment: hoverOut would only fire when I leave .fc-day, no?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I'm only thinking that maybe IE 8 doesn't work the same with child elements as Chrome and Firefox. Perhaps, it's firing the `hoverOut` when you prepend the span. Or maybe it's adding the span outside of `.fc-day`

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep trying. In the meantime I have worked around it with dayRender to mark a range of dates with "Add Activity". Hover would be better though ...

Answer (score 0):

you can put the title tag and work it when hovering

```
 eventMouseover: function(calEvent, domEvent, view) {

                $("a.fc-day-grid-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable").attr("title",'hover me!');
                $("a.fc-day-grid-event.fc-h-event.fc-event.fc-start.fc-end.fc-draggable").attr("data-toggle","tooltip");
           $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
        },
```